# Missing Class and style in Lyx

Tags: 14.04, latex, lyx

I'm a new ubuntu user working with Ubuntu 14.04.02  .

I installed Lyx,i have a little problem with it
I want to download all *the classes and styles*.
What should i do ?

I wrote in the terminal

```
apt-get install Lyx
```

I waited about 30 minutes,i downloaded more than 500Mb .
But i still missing this classes.
I did Reconfigure lyx and i updated it to 2.1.3 but nothing helped.

Comment: Which classes and styles?

Comment: like aa.cls for example

Comment: That's a LaTeX class

Comment: ok , how can i add it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install: *TeX Live: metapackage pulling in all components of TeX Live*

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Caution: These are a few hundred megabytes.

Comment: i will try it now